# How to determine supported cipher suites for Wildfly 10

Tags: java, java-8, tls1.2, wildfly-10

**How can I determine which cipher suites are supported by Wildlfly 10?**

The [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Admin+Guide#AdminGuide-HTTPSlistener) just states that there is an option "enabled-cipher-suites".

*Background*: I'm trying to configure various cipher suites. Example:

```
 <https-listener name="default-ssl" socket-binding="https" security-realm="SslRealm" enabled-cipher-suites="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384" enabled-protocols="TLSv1.2"/>
```

Java version:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_151"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

When I list the availables ciphers for the JVM using [this method](https://confluence.atlassian.com/stashkb/list-ciphers-used-by-jvm-679609085.html) the cipher suite is available.

When starting WildFly no connection is available with a browser and nmap also does not list any available ciphers (using `nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p PORT HOSTNAME`)

There is [a list (capture from the Internet Archive)](https://web.archive.org/web/20210925144425/http://alloutfornoloss.com/jboss-ssl-version-cipher-list/) by someone who used a tool to determine the version, but I think there should be a solution using Wildfly documentation or tools only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out my problem was rather trivial. The JVM which reported the availability of the cipher suite was version 1.8.0_151.
But the Wildfly used another JVM with verson 1.8.0_141 which did not support the cipher.

**Updating the JVM to at least 1.8.0_151 fixed the problem.**